# I am trying to achieve this result using T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below table we have the different amount in different column according to there description. we want to put all the amount in one column and desc in the other using T-SQL script. table name is rawdata.

Current table result :

[image]

```
SSI_CUST_TRANS#  WAYBILL#   BILL_OF_LADING  NET_FREIGHT_CHARGES MISC_CODE1_DESC MISC_CODE1_AMT  MISC_CODE2_DESC MISC_CODE2_AMT  MISC_CODE3_DESC MISC_CODE3_AMT  MISC_CODE4_DESC MISC_CODE4_AMT
3574296 618852  618852  32.5    SPECIAL DELIVERY    40  FUEL SURCHARGE  4.88    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3574319 618852  618852  32.5    SPECIAL DELIVERY    40  FUEL SURCHARGE  4.88    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Required result :

[image]

```
 BILL_OF_LADING WAYBILL#    SSI_CUST_TRANS# Charge Type Desc    Amount
618852  618852  3574296 AMOUNT_PAID     77.38
618852  618852  3574296 NET_FREIGHT_CHARGES ELECTRONIC EQUIP./PARTS 32.5
618852  618852  3574296 SPECIAL DELIVERY        40
618852  618852  3574296 FUEL SURCHARGE      4.88
618852  618852  3574319 AMOUNT_PAID     0
618852  618852  3574319 NET_FREIGHT_CHARGES ELECTRONIC EQUIP./PARTS 32.5
618852  618852  3574319 SPECIAL DELIVERY        40
618852  618852  3574319 FUEL SURCHARGE      4.88
```

We want the amount and description to transpose as shown in the image.

Comment: Please, do not use images, copy and paste actual and expected results.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Then edit your question to include the sample data as DDL+DML statement, and desired results as a table formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From above data tried like this
EXPECTED OUTPUT NEED MORE DATA

```
CREATE TABLE #A
(
SSI_CUST_TRANS BIGINT,
WAYBILL BIGINT,
BILL_OF_LADING BIGINT,
NET_FREIGHT_CHARGES NUMERIC(22,6),
MISC_CODE1_DESC VARCHAR(100),
MISC_CODE1_AMT BIGINT,
MISC_CODE2_DESC VARCHAR(100),
MISC_CODE2_AMT BIGINT,
MISC_CODE3_DESC VARCHAR(100),
MISC_CODE3_AMT BIGINT,
MISC_CODE4_DESC VARCHAR(100),
MISC_CODE4_AMT BIGINT
)
INSERT INTO #A 
(SSI_CUST_TRANS,WAYBILL,BILL_OF_LADING,NET_FREIGHT_CHARGES,MISC_CODE1_DESC,MISC_CODE1_AMT,MISC_CODE2_DESC,MISC_CODE2_AMT)
VALUES

(3574296,618852,618852,32.5,'SPECIAL DELIVERY',40,'FUEL SURCHARGE',4.88),     
(3574319,618852,618852,32.5,'SPECIAL DELIVERY',40,'FUEL SURCHARGE',4.88)       


SELECT DISTINCT BILL_OF_LADING,WAYBILL,SSI_CUST_TRANS,CHARGE_TYPE,NET_FREIGHT_CHARGES,AMOUNT
FROM #A
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (MISC_CODE1_DESC, MISC_CODE1_AMT),
                    (MISC_CODE2_DESC, MISC_CODE2_AMT),
                    (MISC_CODE3_DESC, MISC_CODE3_AMT),
                    (MISC_CODE4_DESC, MISC_CODE4_AMT)
                    ) 
            CROSSAPPLIED (CHARGE_TYPE, AMOUNT)
```

output

```
BILL_OF_LADING  WAYBILL SSI_CUST_TRANS  CHARGE_TYPE NET_FREIGHT_CHARGES AMOUNT
618852  618852  3574296 SPECIAL DELIVERY    32.500000   40
618852  618852  3574296 FUEL SURCHARGE  32.500000   4
618852  618852  3574296 NULL    32.500000   NULL
618852  618852  3574296 NULL    32.500000   NULL
618852  618852  3574319 SPECIAL DELIVERY    32.500000   40
618852  618852  3574319 FUEL SURCHARGE  32.500000   4
618852  618852  3574319 NULL    32.500000   NULL
618852  618852  3574319 NULL    32.500000   NULL
```

Comment: thank you, i will do the other tweaks , thanks a lot